# How to set Tor as a global proxy for ALL traffic (including stuff going out to heroku for instance)

Tags: proxy, osx-leopard, tor

As it says on the tin. I've tried localhost:9510 as per Vidalia setting with no luck.

Tor just adds a proxy address that can be used for that, or am I misunderstanding?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Proxifier](http://www.proxifier.com/mac_download.htm) combined with TOR to route all your traffic via TOR.

Start up Tor and wait for it to connect. After it has connected, you enter the Tor proxy into Proxifier (SOCKS host, 127.0.0.1, PORT 9050) to reroute all of your traffic through Tor. You can also set up rules to route diffrent programs though the proxy or if you want some programs to be routed directly.

Edit: But why would you want to? Routing all traffic through tor would be extreamly slow.. You would be better off using av VPN or a at least a proxy that you're paying for.